# JavaFX Maven platform specific build: mac aarm64 qualifier

Tags: maven, javafx

I am building my JavaFX app using Maven like so:

Dependencies defined in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Maven build command:

```
mvn package -Djavafx.platform=mac
```

This sets the platform qualifier when cross-platform building. The following Maven classifiers are available:

```
win,mac,linux
```

(See https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ 'cross-platform')

Now if I build with the mac classifier, and then try to execute with a aarch64 JRE, this does not work.
Apparently the mac classifier specifies the mac x64 architecture which does not fit to the aarch64 JRE.

Can I somehow specify the aarch64 dependency version for mac?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68000364/maven-include-javafx-dependencies-for-operation-system-i-am-currently-running-on/68001778#68001778) and the profiles of an updated `javafx.pom` like [this](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx/19/javafx-19.pom).

Comment: Excellent, so basically there is a qualifier that includes the arch, like `mac-aarch64`, thanks! When I build with `mvn package -Djavafx.platform=mac-aarch64` it works! If you want to write an answer, I would upvote it!

Answer (score 5):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68000364/maven-include-javafx-dependencies-for-operation-system-i-am-currently-running-on) short of answered a similar issue, but it is now a little bit outdated, as macOS AArch64 support was added starting JavaFX 17.

Before JavaFX 17, the `javafx.pom` [parent pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx/16/javafx-16.pom) included these Maven profiles:

- `linux` with `javafx.platform=linux`
- `macosx` with `javafx.platform=mac`
- `windows` with `javafx.platform=win`
- And a custom profile `javafx.platform.custom` with `javafx.platform=${javafx.platform}`

With the new architectures supported, and starting JavaFX 17, the [parent pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx/17/javafx-17.pom) includes the following Maven profiles:

- `linux-x86_64` with `javafx.platform=linux` or `javafx.platform=linux-monocle`
- `linux-aarch64` with `javafx.platform=linux-aarch64` or `javafx.platform=linux-aarch64-monocle`
- `linux-arm32` with `javafx.platform=linux-arm32-monocle`
- `macosx-x86_64` with `javafx.platform=mac` or `javafx.platform=mac-monocle`
- `macosx-aarch64` with `javafx.platform=mac-aarch64` or `javafx.platform=mac-aarch64-monocle`
- `windows-x86_64` with `javafx.platform=win` or `javafx.platform=win-monocle`
- `windows-x86` with `javafx.platform=win-x86` or `javafx.platform=win-x86-monocle`
- And a custom profile `javafx.platform.custom` with `javafx.platform=${javafx.platform}`

Therefore, if you want to do a cross-platform build that only includes the dependencies for macOS AArch64 you just need:

```
mvn package -Djavafx.platform=mac-aarch64
```

Of course, this only applies to the JavaFX artifacts that Gluon publishes to Maven Center, and not for other distributions (JavaFX SDK or bundled within the Java SDK).

Note: These profiles have a `monocle` alternative, that can be activated if you include a `javafx.monocle` property in your pom:

```
<javafx.monocle>true</javafx.monocle>
```

This allow using the JavaFX artifacts with or without [monocle](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/OpenJFX/Monocle) (the implementation of the Glass windowing component of JavaFX for embedded systems), same as if you download the SDK from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/. This is useful, for instance, if you run on the command line of a Raspberry Pi without a windows manager.

Comment: Thanks! small question, why "monocle"?

Comment: I'll edit the answer to explain it.