Failed to execute goal on project shop: Could not resolve dependencies for project

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project shop:
Could not resolve dependencies for project shop:shop:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
The following artifacts could not be resolved:
org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:${javafx.platform}:22.0.1 (absent),
org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:jar:${javafx.platform}:22.0.1 (absent),
org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:${javafx.platform}:22.0.1 (absent),
org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:${javafx.platform}:22.0.1 (absent):
org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:${javafx.platform}:22.0.1
was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt.
This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is notreattempted until
the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

I just used this command "mvn clean install".
I have tried several times with different modifications in pom.xml file, But this error occurs again and again.
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>shop</groupId>
    <artifactId>shop</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>shop</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit.version>5.10.0</junit.version>
        <javafx.version>22.0.1</javafx.version>
        <javafx.platform>win</javafx.platform> <!-- Ensure this matches your platform -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>${javafx.platform}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>${javafx.platform}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>${javafx.platform}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>${javafx.platform}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>io</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.21.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontawesomefx</artifactId>
            <version>8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.21.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>shop.shop.shop</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <mainClass>shop.shop.shop</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>shop.shop.shop</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>org.openjfx:javafx-base</artifact>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>module-info.class</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </filter>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>org.openjfx:javafx-controls</artifact>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>module-info.class</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </filter>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>org.openjfx:javafx-fxml</artifact>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>module-info.class</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludes>META-INF/*.SF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.RSA</excludes>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>



I don't think you need to add the classifier? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68000364/maven-include-javafx-dependencies-for-operation-system-i-am-currently-running-on

Yes, and there's no corresponding distinction between platforms at Maven central, so remove the classifiers

If I remove the classifiers , the error still occurs
